# How to find a point in a spline at which there is maximum curvature using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following is my code to draw a spline.

```
y = np.array([0.6304,0.6301,0.6283,0.6248,0.6159,0.5924,0.5481,0.4934])
x = np.array([0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.6,3.2,6.4])
tck,u     = interpolate.splprep( [x,y] )
xnew,ynew = interpolate.splev( u, tck)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('linear')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([0.1,10])
plt.plot( x,y,'o' , xnew ,ynew )
plt.legend( [ 'data' , 'spline'] )

plt.show()
```

I need help in finding the point at which there is maximum curvature
Most of the curvature documents that I went through instructs to find the second order differential. But I am stuck here. Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: Wondering what the curvature of a spline on a semi-log scale really means...

Comment: This is actually a graph which is to be drawn for soil consolidation test. Following link is a reference to the final completed graph [link] (https://www.slideshare.net/hronaldo10/class-7-consolidation-test-geotechnical-engineering). slide number 27

Comment: I'm assuming you are using scipy's cubic spline interpolation? If so, you have piece-wise polynomials between your points that are piecewise differentiable. The docs have a section about derivation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html
From this, you can calculate a second derivative by using the first as input. Then you just need to find a local extremum.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226357/second-derivative-in-python-scipy-numpy-pandas